# Button referencing incorrect row in excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, module

I have this block of code which helps a button identify which row it's in. However, when I hide the above row, the button references that hidden row.

For example: if the button is on row 20 and I hide row 19, clicking the button returns row 19. If i hide both rows 19 and 18, the button returns row 18.

It's really weird.

Here is the block which I used to create the button:

```
Sub AddButtons()
  Dim button As button
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim st As Range
  Dim sauce As Integer

  For sauce = 10 To Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
    Set st = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(sauce, 11), Cells(sauce, 11))
    Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(st.Left, st.Top, st.Width, st.Height)

    With button
      .OnAction = "GoToIssue.GoToIssue"
      .Caption = "Go To Source"
      .Name = "Button" & sauce
    End With
  Next sauce
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And here's the block which returns the row ID of the button once it's clicked:

```
Sub GoToIssue()

    Dim b As Object
    Dim myrow As Integer

    Dim hunt As String

    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        myrow = .Row

    End With


    hunt = Worksheets("Dummy").Range("F" & myrow).Value

    'MsgBox hunt

End Sub
```

Your time and help are appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `BottomRightCell`? It appears that it all depends on the size of the button and how it extends. I just did a bunch of testing and it seems `BottomRightCell` is more reliable in terms of showing `Visible` cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function FindButtonRow(btn As Object) As Long
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    '-------------------------------------------------

    Set cell = btn.TopLeftCell

    Do While cell.EntireRow.Hidden
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    FindButtonRow = cell.row

End Function
```

It checks if the cell returned by `TopLeftCell` method is not in hidden row. It if is, the function tries the cell below and so on, as long as it finds the cell from unhidden row.

---

You can use it in your subroutine `GoToIssue` just like that:

```
Sub GoToIssue()

    Dim b As Object
    Dim myrow As Integer

    Dim hunt As String

    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    myrow = FindButtonRow(b)

    hunt = Worksheets("Dummy").Range("F" & myrow).Value

    'MsgBox hunt

End Sub
```